# Javascript KeyCodes not working in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have this game project that allows the user to move around using either the arrow keys or WASD. I have this code to achieve this

In the HTML file:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event){
    if(event.keycode === 87 || event.keycode === 38){
        socket.emit("keyPress",{input: "up", state: true});
    } else if(event.keyCode === 83 || event.keycode === 40){
        socket.emit("keyPress",{input: "down", state: true});
    } else if(event.keyCode === 65 || event.keycode === 37){
        socket.emit("keyPress",{input: "left", state: true});
    } else if(event.keyCode === 68 || event.keycode === 39){
        socket.emit("keyPress",{input: "right", state: true});
    }
};
document.onkeyup = function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 87 || event.keycode === 38){
        socket.emit("keyPress",{input: "up", state: false});
    } else if(event.keyCode == 83 || event.keycode === 40){
        socket.emit("keyPress",{input: "down", state: false});
    } else if(event.keyCode == 65 || event.keycode === 37){
        socket.emit("keyPress",{input: "left", state: false});
    } else if(event.keyCode == 68 || event.keycode === 39){
        socket.emit("keyPress",{input: "right", state: false});
    }
};
```

Now in the JavaScript file:

```
socket.on("keyPress",function(data){
    if(data.input == "up"){
        player.up = data.state;
    } else if(data.input == "down"){
        player.down = data.state;
    } else if(data.input == "left"){
        player.left = data.state;
    } else if(data.input == "right"){
        player.right = data.state;
    }
});
var Player = function(id){
    var self = {
        x: 250,
        y:250,
        id: id,
        up: false,
        down: false,
        left: false,
        right: false,
        speed: 5
    };
    self.updatePosition = function(){
        if(self.up){
            self.y -= self.speed;
        } else if(self.down){
            self.y += self.speed;
        } else if(self.left){
            self.x -= self.speed;
        } else if(self.right){
            self.x += self.speed;
        }
        if(self.x < 0){
            self.x = 0;
        } else if(self.x > 500){
            self.x = 500;
        } else if(self.y < 0){
        self.y = 0;
        } else if(self.y > 500){
            self.y = 500;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

However, the arrow keys do not work, as well as the W key. The ASD keys work perfectly fine.

Why do the arrow keys and W key not work? In the code the KeyCodes are correct, as well as the position updating. How should I make it work?

Comment: `keyCode` !== `keycode` .... use `keyCode` - hint: javascript is case sensitive

Comment: Please see what MDN has to say about [*keyCode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode): "*This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.*" Also, don't use with *keyup* and *keydown* events, better to use *keypress*.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that @JaromandaX thanks for your help.